# php permalink like wordpress permalink

Tags: php, mysql

What i want to do is to create a permalink like system such as the wordpress permalink.

For example:

```
  $value = 'abc';
    if($query_result > 0){
       $value = 'abc1'; // if exists check abc2, abc3, abc4, abc5, etc. etc.
    } else{
      return $value
    }
```

The query results is a search for the number of rows `$query_result = mysql_num_rows`

At this moment i created this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['ajax'])){
    if($_POST['ajax'] == 'pages'){
        echo prettyName($_POST['title']);
    }
}

function prettyName($string)
{
    $echo = strtolower(str_replace(array('  ', ' '), '-', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 s]/', '', trim($string))));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_pretty = '".$echo."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($num){
        $echo = $echo.'-'.pretty2($echo, $num);
    }
    return $echo;
}

function pretty2($echo,$num,$i = 1)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_pretty = '".$echo.'-'.$i."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($num){
        $i++;
        $i = pretty2($echo,$num,$i);
    }
    return $i;
}
```

What does it do:

1. check if `$value` (`$_POST['title']`) exists
2. convert to a prettystring (by example: a b c = a-b-c)
3. check if prettystring exists else +1 (by example: a-b-c exists, a-b-c-1 - a-b-c-9999)
4. loop prettystring until free name doesn't exists.

But what goes wrong is:

if i create a new Post for example:

```
new post 1 name = testpage // results in testpage
new post 2 name = testpage // results in testpage-1
new post 3 name = test-page // results in testpage-2 // should be test-page
```

if i create a new Post with to much whitespaces in it it also get's wrong what could i use to remove all the white spaces? Tried to user TRIM function but that didn't work. Or should i be using javascript to avoid that?

Comment: if row exists add automatically 1,2,3,4,5 etc. etc. behind the $value

Comment: @Jack My question was how could i make an permalink... and if the permalink exists, adds a number behind the post for example: abc, abc1, abc2, abc3 etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will return `abc` if num rows are 0

```
$value = 'abc';
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$num_result = mysql_num_rows($query_result);

if($num_result){
   $value = 'abc1';
}
```

PS. try to use PDO for your next development. A good [Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

for your problem:

```
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `Table1` ORDER BY `name` DESC LIMIT 1");
$num_result = mysql_num_rows($query_result);

if($num_result){
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);
   $value = (int)str_replace('abc', '', $row['name']);
   $value = 'abc'.($value+1);
}
```

Comment: that is not an answer. i need a loop, with or without PDO.

Comment: That's not a real question. What exactly do you want to do? What is your query? What do you want to return?

Comment: if the value exist add a number behind it. example: abc (exists) generate abc1 (if this one exists, generate abc2).

Comment: See my solution, but thanks anyway

Comment: could you also review my question again? Regards, Ray